# Sharepoint 2013 JSLINK template with view grouping rendering

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part, view, rendering-template, jslink

I'm looking for a tutorial or documentation on how to create a JSLINK rendering template that will perform view grouping rendering. I need to use this in connection with the list view webpart, where I have configured its view to group items by a given field. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way to make it work:

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Group = CustomGroup;

function CustomGroup(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, expand) {
    var html = '<div style="float:left">' + listItem[group] + ' : </div>';
    return html;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it does modify the Grouping section, however, the issue I am having is that all of my Grouping sections are enlisted without the items that belong to them, and then all items are stacked below the groupings. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems that a workaround addressing this issue is being discussed here:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149622/csr-is-also-applied-to-a-group-by-header-in-a-listview

Comment: Make sure you have selected the group to be shown expanded and not default collapsed

Answer (score 1):

[Martin Hatch](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1-overview-url-tokens-and-applying-jslink-to-objects.html) has a series on how to use JSLink

The following items are or will be covered

- Part 1 – Overview, URL Tokens and Applying JSLink to objects
- Part 2 – Changing how individual fields display
- Part 3 – Creating a custom editing interface
- Part 4 – Validating user input
- Part 5 – Creating custom List Views
- Part 6 – Creating View Templates and Deployment Options
- Part 7 – Code Samples