# Group by field using jQuery

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, css, html

Say I didn't want to use the Group By option in an out of the box view to group my list by a certain field.

Is there a way to achieve this using jQuery, JavaScript or something other front-end code?

Comment: Just curious... What is the reason you don't want to use the native Group By ?

Comment: It's a custom web part that aggregates data and was written a long time ago.  They want to group the data like the out of the box web parts do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSLink which comes with every SharePoint List. This enables you to render content using your own code. Try [this](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html) post for a complete guide on JSLink and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78145/sharepoint-2013-jslink-template-with-view-grouping-rendering) for grouping content.

Hope this helps you to start in the right direction.

Comment: Wait.  Isn't JSLink only a SP 2013 thing?  I'm working with 2010.

Comment: Maybe XSLT is the way to go? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff606773(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Oh, I thought it was for 2013. Tough luck.